# Mount filesystem from local computer that is not mine without monitor nor keyboard

Tags: filesystems, mount, nfs, nmap, arp

Ok, that’s a weird one.

### Set Up

The thing is that I found an old PC tower that belonged to a family member and that most likely has a Linux on it.

It doesn’t have an HDMI port, so I can’t use that, nor can I use the VGA port because I don’t have the cable.

So, my setup right now is that the PC tower is turned on, and connected via Ethernet to the router (but I don’t know its IP address)

### Goal

What I want to achieve is to mount the PC’s file system on my laptop (which doesn’t have an Ethernet port) in order to retrieve the potential data on it. Then, I will install over the LAN network a new Linux distro.

What can I do to get there?

### What I’ve tried

I am stuck at the very first step: I can’t even get its ip address!

I’ve done `nmap` scans with OS detection, and the different parameters `-Pn` `-sn` `-sL` and without anything at all. I’ve also executed the `arp` command, `arp-scan`, with sudo etc. in vain.

I can’t seem to find how to identify the PC’s ip address.

If you have other suggestions on how I should go about it to get access to the file system/retrieve data and then boot up with a fresh install of a Linux distro, I’m open.

Comment: Don't you have access to the router's admin console? It will tell you the IP address as well as the MAC address.